# Why PySpark partitionBy isn't working properly?

Tags: pyspark

I have a table as:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| COMP | 0005 | 2008-08-04 |
| COMP | 0009 | 2002-01-01 |
| COMP | 01.0 | 2002-01-01 |
| COMP | 0005 | 2008-01-01 |
| COMP | 0005 | 2001-10-20 |
| CTEC | 0009 | 2001-10-20 |
| COMP | 0005 | 2009-10-01 |
| COMP | 01.0 | 2003-07-01 |
| COMP | 02.0 | 2004-01-01 |
| CTEC | 0009 | 2021-09-24 |

At first I want to partition the table on COL1, then do another partition on COL2, then sort the COL3 in descending order. Then I'm trying to add row number.

I write:

```
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy(col("COL1")).partitionBy(col("COl2")).orderBy(desc("COL3"))
TBL = TBL.withColumn(f"RANK", F.row_number().over(windowSpec))
```

**My expected output is this:**

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| COMP | 0005 | 2009-10-01 | 1 |
| COMP | 0005 | 2008-08-04 | 2 |
| COMP | 0005 | 2008-01-01 | 3 |
| COMP | 0005 | 2001-10-20 | 4 |
| COMP | 0009 | 2002-01-01 | 1 |
| COMP | 01.0 | 2003-07-01 | 1 |
| COMP | 01.0 | 2002-01-01 | 2 |
| COMP | 02.0 | 2004-01-01 | 1 |
| CTEC | 0009 | 2021-09-24 | 1 |
| CTEC | 0009 | 2001-10-20 | 2 |

**But the output I'm getting is like this:**

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| COMP | 0005 | 2009-10-01 | 1 |
| COMP | 0005 | 2008-08-04 | 2 |
| COMP | 0005 | 2008-01-01 | 3 |
| COMP | 0005 | 2001-10-20 | 4 |
| COMP | 0009 | 2002-01-01 | **2** |
| COMP | 01.0 | 2003-07-01 | 1 |
| COMP | 01.0 | 2002-01-01 | 2 |
| COMP | 02.0 | 2004-01-01 | 1 |
| CTEC | 0009 | 2021-09-24 | 1 |
| CTEC | 0009 | 2001-10-20 | **3** |

Can anyone please help me to figure out where I'm doing the mistake??

Comment: wrong syntax -- use `partitionBy('col1', 'col2').orderBy()`

Comment: Thanks @samkart!! It works. But can you tell me what was wrong in my code? Was it skipping COL1 for partitioning?

Comment: yes, it only considered the last partitionBy before the orderBy